# Sequence m(k) with $\frac{m(k)}{3\cdot k\cdot log(k)}>0$ for $k\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm looking for a sequence m(k) which fullfills the condition $\frac{m(k)}{3\cdot k\cdot log(k)}>0$ for $k\rightarrow\infty$. log(k) means the natural logarithm and m,k are positive integers.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Let $m_{k} := 3k^{2}$ for all $k \geq 1$. Then $(m_{k})$ is a desired choice.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, it is enough to set
$$
m(k)=k^{1+\varepsilon}.
$$

For a more interesting solution, you could choose 
$$
m(k)=4p_k,
$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime :)